# async response for two different calls with TPL

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a textbox that accepts input and sends async request to server.

First i typed 'a' and send async request with 'a'. Then i immediately typed 'b' and sends request with 'ab'.

Response for 'ab' is returned faster than response for 'a'. So i ended up getting response for 'a' even though textbox has value 'ab'

I tried with, but it displays last response (which is for 'a')

```
Task.Run(() => { 
        // send request
}).ContinueWith((t) => {
       // get response
});
```

I am somewhat newbiew. Can anyone help me how to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to ensure that the previous request is reliably cancelled when a new one is dispatched. It takes a bit of plumbing, but once you get your head around the pattern it's not difficult:

```
CancellationTokenSource TextBoxCancellationTokenSource;

async void TextBox_TextChanged()
{
    // Harvest values needed to make the request *before* the first await.
    string requestArg = TextBox.Text;

    if (TextBoxCancellationTokenSource != null)
    {
        // Cancel previous request.
        TextBoxCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    TextBoxCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    CancellationToken cancellationToken = TextBoxCancellationTokenSource.Token;

    try
    {
        // Optional: a bit of throttling reducing the number
        // of server requests if the user is typing quickly.
        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Must be checked after every await.

        var response = await Task.Run(() => GetResponse(requestArg), cancellationToken);

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Must be checked after every await.

        ProcessResponse(response);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Expected.
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: the above requires that new requests are always queued from a single thread (UI thread most likely).

Comment: Thanks for the response. One clarification, if there are three request for 'a', 'ab', 'abc' and my last response is for 'abc' - using cancellation will throw exception two times (for previous 'a' and 'ab'), right?

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam, that depends on how quickly the user is typing. If they're typing really fast, 'a' and 'ab' operations will be cancelled, yes. The slower they type, the more operations will actually run to completion and end up getting to the "process/display response" part - without exceptions.